# Unable to see the logs in grafana dashboard for kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, grafana-loki

I am unable to see the logs in grafana dashboards for k8s cluster, logs are generating but not showing on dashbord.
Also i can see the Non Formatted Logs but not able to see the formatted logs and some matric. Please let me know how i can resolve this issue.

I have checked the config file for grafana and also configmap for logs.

Comment: Hello @Bhagavat Bhise, Did you had time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your problem? Please let me know if you have any further queries.

Answer (score 0):

Check the problem may be that the CSS and JavaScript files have not been loaded.This mostly happens because you may be using a proxy. Check the `auth.proxy` section in your config. Like `server.domain config` value and the `server.root_url` value, refer to [Run Grafana behind a reverse proxy](https://grafana.com/tutorials/run-grafana-behind-a-proxy/#running-grafana-behind-a-reverse-proxy) for additional details.

Check when you are accessing grafana directly (via NodePort) working or not? As soon as you try to use an ingress (reverse proxy) and add `GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL` you get the result. When you had a look into the `*.css and *.js resources` which are getting loaded do NOT contain CSS or JS code but the same HTML code from the initial HTML call.

Finally check you may have misconfigured the ingress. Using traefik as ingress controller / reverseproxy you had to add to the ingress annotations.

```
traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/rule-type: PathPrefixStrip
```

The above leads to the effect that the HTML was written in every other file.

Refer to [Grafana dashboard not showing](https://community.grafana.com/t/grafana-dashboard-not-showing/896) on Official Grafana labs community for more information.

If you still encounter a problem, then you can check the Grafana server log. Usually located at `/var/log/grafana/grafana.log` on Unix systems or in `<grafana_install_dir>/data/log` on other platforms and manual installations.

Refer to [Troubleshooting](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/troubleshooting/#troubleshooting) Grafana issues and [“Data source connected, but no labels received. Verify that Loki and Promtail are configured properly.](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/troubleshooting/#troubleshooting)” for more information.